# Is Zend_Service_Twitter usable/updated?

Tags: php, zend-framework, twitter, oauth

I found that many functions thats documented in [`Zend_Service_Twitter`](http://zendframework.com/manual/1.10/en/zend.service.twitter.html) seem to be no longer working, or maybe i did the wrong thing.

```
Zend_Debug::dump($twitter->account->verifyCredentials());
```

returned

```
object(Zend_Rest_Client_Result)#50 (2) {
  ["_sxml":protected] => object(SimpleXMLElement)#55 (2) {
    ["request"] => string(33) "/1/account/verify_credentials.xml"
    ["error"] => string(19) "Incorrect signature"
  }
  ["_errstr":protected] => NULL
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might very well be the case, as Twitter has updated their oAuth Authentication. It also broke my own oAuth Library. The big difference I found was that they added a `oauth_verifier`, which I did not remember for seeing in the original oAuth documentation when I was building my own library.

This diagram on Twitter's Developer page helps explain.

- http://a0.twimg.com/images/dev/oauth_diagram.png

I can't really help you with the rest of your problem as I don't use the Zend Framework myself, but I think your assumption that it needs an update is correct.

Comment: ZF has been updated. The OAuth procedure for Zend_Service_Twitter is documented in Example #1 at http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.service.twitter.html

Comment: I wasn't talking about the switch to oAuth itself, because I already figured that was being used (which is good). But before the permanent switch to oAuth it's support on Twitter had been flaky (in my experience), and just recently I had to perform a couple of changed to the oAuth flow to make it work again. But I just downloaded ZF 1.10.8 and checked, that's not the problem here.

Comment: @Gzipp, example 1 is the same as the code i shown? i tried to run `verifyCredentials()`

Comment: Well and good. I was just pointing out that the Zend Twitter class and documentation had been updated, be it flaky or not. The old stuff had worked well for me, but my usage was fairly limited.